# AWS S3 Bucket, can't get head-object from file

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I was faced with the following problem :
When I upload new file use the `signed url` and then try get head-object from uploaded file S3, using `aws-sdk`, I get error `Forbidden`, but if I upload new file use AWS console, I can get head-object. Does anyone know what the problem ?

Comment: What about the opposite?  If you upload a file from code, can you download it from the console?  Does it appear to be at the correct path in the console?

Comment: The challenge was to use the signed url for uploading new files  to S3 bucket.

Comment: I understand that, but I was trying to determine whether the problem was with the download, or whether the problem was actually with the upload, which only *appeared* to succeed but didn't create the object the way you intended.  Also, you can't reuse the signed URL from a `PUT` to do a `GET`... you need a new signed URL for that because the REST verb (`PUT`, `GET`, `DELETE`, etc.) is incorporated into the signature -- a signed URL can only perform the operation specified when it was signed.

Comment: Thank you dude! It was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify correct [ACL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html) in presigned POST url.
For example set (`bucket-owner-full-control`):

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var params = { Bucket: req.body.bucketname, ACL: 'bucket-owner-full-control', Key: req.body.name, ContentType: req.body.type };
s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function (err, url) ....
```

Comment: Hello thank u for answer. I tried and I got the same error

Comment: hmmm, strange, let me look into it little more

Comment: It's my code:
`let parameters = {
  Bucket: bucket,
  Key:'123/example.wav',
  ACL: 'bucket-owner-full-control'
}
console.log(s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', parameters))
`
Then I upload new file using curl.

After the ways I try to get head object using the code :
`let params = {
  Bucket: bucket,
  Key: '123/example.wav'
};

s3.headObject(params, (err, data) => {
  if (err) console.log('ERRsRR', err)
  console.log('data', data)
})`